# Trace of call stack in haskell with variables

Tags: debugging, haskell, stack-trace, callstack

Is there anyway to trace haskell execution step by step? I mean i wanna see every call of function with variable values. Something smilar to prolog trace/guitrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I know of today is [HTrace](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/htrace/0.1/doc/html/Debug-HTrace.html) which uses indentation to denote call-depth. It's still a far cry away from what you're looking for, but it can be very useful for checking intuition.

Comment: well tired as hell but was worth trying